# How to extract cells of a particular colour in pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

I have applied a conditional formatting to a column of a pivot table in Excel, which automatically colours the cells greater than a particular value in red.

I also want to extract those red cells separately to a specific area in the same Sheet.

Can it be done by using macros or an 'if' condition would help here?

Comment: I actually want those very red cells to separately appear at some other location in the sheet for calculation purposes. Can you suggest me something for this?

Comment: Haha..dude...it has to be done automatically..for change in value everytime..!!

Answer (score 0):

What is your conditional formatting parameter?  You could use the same logic programmatically.  Alternatively you could write the code to check the color of the cell.

```
'specify the cell you want the color for
x = InputBox("what cell")
Range("a1") = Range(x).Interior.Color


If Range(x).Interior.Color = Range("a1") Then
MsgBox "yes the color is right"
End If
```

for a pivot table example

```
'where cell is something your looking for that is in the cell
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "'cell'", xlDataAndLabel + xlFirstRow, True
 x = Selection.Interior.Color
```

Comment: If the data in the column is greater than a particular number(which also changes dynamically), then the cells turn red. I tried checking the color but it doesn't work with Pivot tables.

Comment: so use the same equation that you're using in the pivot table or conditional formatting with vba.  alternatively you can check the pivot table color however you need to call the pivot table not the cell range when your coloring is on the pivot table design.